# jQuery UI draggable: Access dragged element when using helper: clone

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a set of jquery UI draggables that are connected to a sortable via `helper: 'clone'`. In the `receive` event of the draggable I want to access the element that just got put into the list, but there does not seem to be any way of doing this.

My code is similar to this:

```js
$('#drag li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    connectToSortable: '#sort'
});

$('#sort').sortable({
    receive: function(evt, ui) {
        ui.item.css('color', 'green');
        ui.helper.css('color', 'green');
    }
});
```

`ui.item` refers to the original draggable, pre-clone, while `ui.helper` seems to not exist anywhere in the document after the item has been dropped.

See this jsfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/KSuPX/

Update: Sorry if my actual question is a bit unclear. A summary:

When the sortable list receives a new element, how do I access that element?

Comment: could you please explain your question clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Sortable and draggable are 2 different widgets and maybe you would need edit the .js file if no solution works. And unfortunately jQuery UI does not provide detailed examples on how these functions work. You could try using the option 'sender' under receive as mentioned here - http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive

Comment: They are different widgets, but designed to work together (via the `connectToSortable` parameter). `sender` in this instance refers to the original draggable object, not the cloned dragged object.